# Pattern match nth block of digits in a string

Tags: regex, t-sql

This is actually more a regex question instead of a SQL question, so here goes:
I have a stored procedure where I need to compare a string to check the 4th "group" of characters.
Say I have a string like this G7-8855-99-443-8877
What I want is the 4th "block" of digits, ie. 443 
Another way to say this is the group that comes between the 3rd and 4th dash.
The blocks that are separated with the dash can be from 1 to 3 alphanumeric values.

The other option I could use is to split the string

[edit]
Im using TSQL

Comment: You have all the options, what's stopping you from trying them?

Comment: `^[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-([^-]*)-.*$` get the string you want from group index 1. http://regex101.com/r/jD3yD9/1

Comment: Which lang are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities based on what you were thinking of doing.  They both use SQLCLR. One uses a RegEx capture group, the other splits the string.  You can find plenty of examples across many sites on how to do both, or you can just download the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library (which I wrote, but these functions shown here are in the Free version).

```sql
-- If there are always 4 dashes, capture what is between the last 2 dashes
-- (the rest of the match is discarded as we are only grabbing what is in the group)
SELECT SQL#.RegEx_CaptureGroup(N'G7-8855-99-443-8877', N'-([^-]*)-[^-]*$',
                               1, NULL, 1, 0, '');

-- If there are always 4 dashes, match what is between the last 2 dashes
-- (using positive lookbehind and lookahead since they aren't part of the match)
SELECT SQL#.RegEx_MatchSimple4k(N'G7-8855-99-443-8877', N'(?<=-)[^-]*(?=-[^-]*$)',
                                1, '');

-- Using a string split.
-- For single values this is fine, but for using in a query the scalar functions
-- above are probably better.
SELECT split.SplitVal
FROM   SQL#.String_Split4k(N'G7-8855-99-443-8877', N'-', 1) split
WHERE  split.SplitNum = 4
```